# Adding library to fortran project eclipse

Tags: eclipse, fortran, lapack

I have a FORTRAN 90 code and I use Eclipse to run the code. The code uses LAPACK library for solving a system of linear equations. My question is how can I add the LAPACK library to the project and make it run.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using gfortran, but this is how I do it:

- Right Click on your project
- Properties
- Fortran build
- Settings
- Tool Settings tab
- Fortran Linker
- Libraries

Add `lapack` and `blas` to the `Libraries (-l)` box. You might also have to include the location of Lapack in the `Library search path (-L)`, but not necessarily. (I have installed Lapack with my ubuntu software package manager, and the linker finds the libraries automatically.)

Comment: Thanks for your response, although I saw it late. Now I have `opensuse` and I do exactly what you say. But, I think I don't undestand the last part of your answer. Here is what I do: after going to the Libraries of my project I just click add and go to the downloaded repository. I have also downloaded LAPACK from `yast`, but my system doesn't recognize it automatically. I guess I am missing a step in between. I didn't get what you mean by `linker`